# Spring Data JPA закрывается соеденение с БД

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

Имеется Spring boot приложение, которое перегоняет большое количество данных получаемых по API в удаленную БД (MySQL). В качестве пула соединений использую HikariCP, вот его конфигурация в момент запуска приложения:

```
HikariPool-1 - configuration: 
allowPoolSuspension.............false 
autoCommit......................false 
catalog.........................none 
connectionInitSql...............none 
connectionTestQuery.............none 
connectionTimeout...............30000 
dataSource......................none 
dataSourceClassName.............none 
dataSourceJNDI..................none 
dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>} 
driverClassName................."com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" 
healthCheckProperties...........{} 
healthCheckRegistry.............none 2019-02-21 13:00:32:351 [main] DEBUG c.z.h.HikariConfig.logConfiguration() - idleTimeout.....................600000 
initializationFailTimeout.......1 
isolateInternalQueries..........false 
jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://url/db_name?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&failOverReadOnly=false 
leakDetectionThreshold..........0 
maxLifetime.....................1800000 
maximumPoolSize.................10 
metricRegistry..................none 
metricsTrackerFactory...........none 
minimumIdle.....................10 
password........................<masked> 
poolName........................"HikariPool-1" 
readOnly........................false 
registerMbeans..................false 
scheduledExecutor...............none 
schema..........................none 
threadFactory...................internal 
transactionIsolation............default 
username........................"name" 
validationTimeout...............5000
```

В течении работы появляется лог: `HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)`

А через несколько минут работы валится исключение:

```
2019-02-21 12:56:22:323 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.z.h.p.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection() - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@4169569c: (connection is dead) 
2019-02-21 12:56:22:327 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.z.h.p.HikariPool.createPoolEntry() - HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:706)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:692)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 17 common frames omitted

2019-02-21 12:56:28:238 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG c.z.h.p.HikariPool.logPoolState() - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=1) 
2019-02-21 12:56:30:417 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.z.h.p.HikariPool.createPoolEntry() - HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
```

Пробовал устанавливать `max-lifetime: 25800, maximum-pool-size: 20, minimum-idle: 0, idle-timeout: 30000` - результат всегда такой же. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD:

Вывод таймаутов из БД:

```
connect_timeout 10
deadlock_timeout_long 50000000
deadlock_timeout_short 10000
delayed_insert_timeout 300
innodb_lock_wait_timeout 50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout OFF
interactive_timeout 28800
lock_wait_timeout 31536000
net_read_timeout 30
net_write_timeout 600
slave_net_timeout 3600
thread_pool_idle_timeout 60
wait_timeout 28800
```

UPD2.

В ходе работы выходит лог:

```
[yourPoolName connection closer] DEBUG c.z.h.p.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection() - yourPoolName - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@742e0612: (connection has passed maxLifetime) 
[yourPoolName connection adder] DEBUG c.z.h.p.HikariPool.call() - yourPoolName - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@16e8fb27
```

UPD3

Выяснилось, что на удаленном сервере падает MySQL. Провайдер говорит нехватка памяти. Что может забивать память? Может какой-то кэш MySQL?

Comment: "The driver has not received any packets from the server." Означает что проблема на стороне сервера. Драйвер не получает от него пакетов.

Comment: @talex 
`connect_timeout 10`  
`deadlock_timeout_long 50000000`  
`deadlock_timeout_short 10000`  
`delayed_insert_timeout 300`  
`innodb_lock_wait_timeout 50`  
`innodb_rollback_on_timeout OFF`  
`interactive_timeout 28800`  
`lock_wait_timeout 31536000`  
`net_read_timeout 30`  
`net_write_timeout 600`  
`slave_net_timeout 3600`  
`thread_pool_idle_timeout 60`  
`wait_timeout 28800`  

Вот вывод таймаутов из БД.

Comment: А если открыть соединение с `mysql` из коммандной строки или SQLDeveloper-ом или MySQL Workbench - соединение нормально держится?

Comment: @AlexYu запустил в бесконечном цикле выборку поштучно средствами `java.sql.*`, никаких ошибок нет. При этом `Connection` я инициализирую всего один раз и не закрываю в цикле.

Comment: Хм. Значит подозрение на HikaryCP. Вы писали: "пробовал установить maximum-pool-size: 20" - а было ли замечено какое-нибудь отличие в поведении? Исключения возникают раньше-позже-одинаково? А что произойдет если **уменьшить** размер пула до минимума? Вообще попробовать последовательно: 1, 2, 4, 8 - будут ли возникать исключения и как скоро?

Comment: @AlexYu пул пробовал и 1 и 100. Работает примерно 8 минут, после чего валится. Никаких изменений не заметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась вовсе не в `Hikari`, `Hibernate` и т.д. В момент загрузки данных в БД, я так же использовал `com.jcraft.jsch.JSch` библиотеку, для загрузки изображений и не правильно использовал настройки соединения с сервером, чем вызывал переполнение памяти.